# Obtaining associated file type icons in ios

Tags: ios

I have downloaded a list of file names from a RESTful web service and populated a UITableView with the file names.  Now, in the cell's image, I would like to display an icon for each of the file names that have associated apps on the ios device (just like you would see in a normal list of files). eg pdf, doc etc.  Where/how can I obtain each associated app and its icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I sorted it out. 
To obtain an associated filetype icon you can use UIDocumentInteractionController. It has a property called icons which provides an array of icons for the file in the url that you initialise UIDocumentInteractionController with. The big advantage for my circumstance is that the file url that you supply does not have to exist. So in my case I just used this snippet in the UITableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
NameIdPair *doc = [self.lstDocs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // obtain file name
cell.textLabel.text = doc.Name;
NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:doc.Name];
UIDocumentInteractionController *di = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileUrl];
cell.imageView.image = di.icons[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Where/how can I obtain each associated app and its icon?

```
Where
```

This data may be gotten from webservice.

```
How
```

In storey board use custom cell to define it as your requirement. [**Here is example**](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/).

Comment: Thanks, but the webservice doesn't provide anything but a list of file names. I don't want to display a thumbnail, I want to display the icon specified by the associated app on that ios device

Comment: You may add icons of files to resources folder and then get them to dispaly